# Select method of Range Class failed using ThisWorkbook

Tags: vsto, office-interop, com-interop, office-2016

```
 Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
    wb.Activate
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
```

Ps: Some times above code working properly ,most of times throwing exception

Looking at this link
[Run Time Error '1004': Select method of Range Class failed using ThisWorkbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165887/run-time-error-1004-select-method-of-range-class-failed-using-thisworkbook) i did the same as above still failing

Answer (score 0):

try to fist activate the sheet and then use the select but first of all do you really need the select? It's the most expensive method you can call (still sometimes needed)

If you just need to read/write a value into the cell you can do it this way

```
Dim wkb as Workbook
Dim wks as Worksheet

wkb = Application.Workbooks("Book2.xlsx")
wks = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(wks.Range("A1").Value2)
' or use this code for selecting
' With wks
'   .Activate()  ' not really sure you need it, test it
'   .Range("A1").Select
' End With
```

Comment: wb = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fileName, ReadOnly:=False)
            wb.Activate()
   TemplateSheet = Globals.ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Globals.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet)
   TemplateSheet.Activate()
                    TemplateSheet.Cells(1, 1).select()                                   
 Even i tried activating the sheet, Though it's not working

Comment: I guess it throws the error on the last line? Try if the sheet activate command works. I can't test now don't have Visual Studio with me. Just tested in VBA this and it seems to be working
`Sub test()

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Application.Workbooks.Add
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets.Add
    wks.Activate
    
    wks.Cells(10, 1).Select
    
End Sub`

Comment: I tried with sheet activate command. It works some times, some times it throws the error. Strange..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reference a range in a different sheet, you can't use select metod. you should write your code as following

```
Application.Goto Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```